# This context inside class

Tags: javascript

Consider following class and calling `foo` method: (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpvbd9LL/2/)

```
function MyClass() {
    this.Prop = "Hello";
}

MyClass.prototype.foo = function () {
    var self = this;
    $("<p>" + self.Prop + "</p>").appendTo("#result");
}

function sampleMethod(callback) {
    // do magic stuff
    callback();
}

function executeMethod() {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    sampleMethod(function() {
       myClass.foo(); 
    });
    sampleMethod(myClass.foo);
}

(function() {
   executeMethod();
})();
```

The output:

> Hello
>
> undefined

As you can see, there is a big difference between calls:

```
sampleMethod(function() {
   myClass.foo(); 
});

sampleMethod(myClass.foo);
```

Why that happens? How to write a class to prevent such a situation?

Comment: What kind of situation? The only difference between the two calls is that you wrapped the class-function in an anonymous function. In essence this makes no difference (at least not if you're not returning anything)...

Comment: @somethinghere see my edit: I've pasted a result from jsFiddle.

Comment: Oh it is simply because you have not instantiated the method yet. Defining a method does not execute it. You need to try `var test = new MyClass()` and then pass sampleMethod `test.foo`.

Comment: @somethinghere `myClass` is instantied: `var myClass = new MyClass();`.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one too late. Let me have another look :)

Comment: Bind the function to the object scope -> sampleMethod(myClass.foo.apply(myClass));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that sampleMethod(myClass.foo); pass function of myClass but not in class context, if you test the current object this, you will see that is window, the global one.

If you declare sampleMethod in the object context, you could do something like that.

Comment: So, I can't do anything in class definition to prevent that situation? I work in C#, so passing function in that way preserves the context of instance. It's strange to me because it looks like via `sampleMethod(myClass.foo)` I just past "body" of a function (without instance of object that it was called on) right?

Comment: The declaration is not strict in JS... Could you give use more informations about the usage you want ? 
You are right, it just passes the body of the function.

Comment: Ok, the  reason of  usage were simply.. less code :) (simple passing function name instead of creating anynmous function especially for it), but I now see that the scope is lost.

Comment: or bind to the object scope -> sampleMethod(myClass.foo.apply(myClass));

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by passing the parent scope to the anonymous function executioner, like this:

```
function sampleMethod(callback, scope) {
    if(scope) scope[callback]();
    else callback();
}

function executeMethod() {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    sampleMethod(function() {
       myClass.foo(); 
    });
    sampleMethod("foo", myClass);
}
```

The problem is that you are trying to pass a function of a -for the sampleMethod- unexisting scope. So if you pass both you can call them as you need to.

Comment: He also could do (in a cleaner way):
function sampleMethod(callback, scope) {
    scope.callback = callback;
    scope.callback();
}
This solution is often used to use function in object scope.

Comment: the even cleaner way is using `call` like this `callback.call(scope);`

Comment: @King King - with the `callback.call(scope)` can scope be 'undefined' or 'false'? Otherwise we would still need an if statement, stopping the simplification. Otherwise, all great suggestions!

Comment: the `scope` is supposed to be the object having the method `callback` (the `myClass` object in the OP's code). So of course we may need to perform some check first.